# TI TM4C - Why does setting GPIOCR go straight to BusFault?

Tags: c

So I'm programming a TI Tiva C Launchpad (TM4C123GH6PM) to just simply change LED color based on switch input. This should be relatively simple, but I'm having trouble unlocking my desired Port F and writing the commit bits. When I go to write the CR bits (in other words, to enable the switches) the debugger goes straight to "BusFault_Handler."

My code up to that point is as follows:

```
#define GPIOLock_PortF (*(unsigned int*)0x40025520)
#define GPIOCR_PortF (*(unsigned int*)0x40025524)
#define Unlock ((unsigned int)0x4C4F434B)
#define SWs ((unsigned int)0x11)

int main(){

GPIOLock_PortF = Unlock; //undo GPIOLock to get to GPIOCR
GPIOCR_PortF = SWs; //enable commit for switches
```

As soon I try to run the first assembly instruction for that last line of C...

```
MOVS R0, #17
```

...the debugger just drops to "BusFault_Handler."

Can anyone see something obviously wrong here? Have I misunderstood the datasheet?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have missed to enable the clock for GPIOs for PortF

The Initialisation Procedure is stated in the datasheet page 656 here

http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/spms376e/spms376e.pdf

you have to enable clock to Port F page 340.

```
#define SYSCTL_RCGC2_R  (*(unsigned int *)0x400FE108)    
#define GPIOLock_PortF (*(unsigned int*)0x40025520)
#define GPIOCR_PortF (*(unsigned int*)0x40025524)
#define Unlock ((unsigned int)0x4C4F434B)
#define SWs ((unsigned int)0x11)

int main(){
  SYSCTL_RCGC2_R |= 0x00000020; // enable clock for PortF
  GPIOLock_PortF = Unlock; //undo GPIOLock to get to GPIOCR
  GPIOCR_PortF = SWs; //enable commit for switches
```

Comment: Ahh, that was it. I did have Clock Enable in my code but I had it after the unlock, instead of before it.